# Random chinese characters on attempt to copy clipboard from X forwarded ssh session

Tags: ssh, openssh, clipboard, xorg

I use X forwarding with a debian server running openssh so that I can directly copy over error messages I see in tmux to my local machine.

Twice it happened that instead of getting the intended text on my clipboard, I got some gibberish chinese (as detected by google translate) characters, and this time I saved it.

```
䅆䱉›桔⁥偃⁕潹牵洠捡楨敮椠⁳畲湮湩⁧湯搠敯⁳潮⁴畳灰牯⁴桴⁥卓⁅⸴′湩瑳畲瑣潩⁮敳ⱴ眠楨档椠⁳敲畱物摥映牯漠敮漠⁦桴⁥敳癲捩獥匠湥牴⁹獵獥⠠汃捩桫畯敳)
```

I can't make any sense of it. The original text was a bash error message in english, copied from tmux. **My main question is: why is this happening?** It appears to be absolute gibberish based on what google is translating it to.

Only I have access to the server (key-based auth, passwords disabled), and I have tried to make sure that no one except me is/has logged into the server by inspecting running processes and logs, but perhaps I'm missing something so I've included details in the footnote.

My hypothesis is that perhaps there's some encoding error that's happening which is causing legitimate copied text to appear as gibberish? If so, are there known open bugs I can track?

---

###### Footnote

```
$ sudo netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          127.0.0.1:34570         ESTABLISHED 1978210/sshd: debia
tcp        0      0 <server-ip>:22          <server-ip>:49944       ESTABLISHED 4786/sshd: root@not
tcp        0    428 <server-ip>:22          <my-ip>:50827           ESTABLISHED 1978104/sshd: debia
```

```
$ ps auxwww | grep sshd:
root        4786  0.0  0.0  16988  8068 ?        Ss   Aug07   0:10 sshd: root@notty
root     1978104  0.0  0.0  16612  7972 ?        Ss   15:22   0:00 sshd: debian [priv]
debian   1978210  0.0  0.0  16612  4808 ?        S    15:23   0:00 sshd: debian@pts/19
debian   1982187  0.0  0.0   6144  2284 pts/33   S+   15:25   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd:
```

Only weird thing I noticed are these entries in `last`:

```
debian   pts/34       tmux(3007).%51   Fri Aug 13 15:13   still logged in
debian   pts/33       tmux(3007).%50   Fri Aug 13 15:12   still logged in
debian   pts/32       tmux(3007).%49   Fri Aug 13 15:12   still logged in
```

any entry with an IP, I recognize it. But I'm not sure what the entries without the IP mean.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich makes sense, I posted here because it raised security eyebrows. In that case, can we vote to migrate it  to superuser so I don't have to cross post?

Comment: I also added details about what the original copied text was.

Comment: *"...  can we vote to migrate it to superuser so I don't have to cross post?  "* - I've voted to migrate it, but it will need more votes or a moderator. Just wait. But I think there are some "invisible characters" which are part of the copied data and which might cause the data to be interpreted as utf.-8 or utf-16 or so. Pasting the output into a file might reveal what actually got copy+paste.

Comment: This is an encoding error. Decided as UTF-16LE and then reencoded as ASCII, it reads "*FAIL: The CPU your machine is running on does not support the SSE 4.2 instruction set, which is required for one of the services Sentry uses (Clickhouse)*"

Comment: @nobody yes, I believe that's what the message was! I'm wondering if this is an issue with my ssh client / server / X11 or clipboard and where this belongs as a bug report.